# Predict Future Progression of Time series Based on Set of Similar Time Series

Tags: time-series, predictive-models

I have recorded the download activity over time for multiple files (=observations). I have transformed the data to consist of the number of cumulated downloads at regular measurement intervals (e.g. hours or days). The observed files have been published at different points in time, i.e. there is missing data at the tail end.

Example data:

```
filename  day0 day1 day2 day3 day4 day5 day6
file_01   10   15   18   21   22   22   23
file_02   13   19   22   23   24   24 
file_03   11   16   18   20   21 
file_04   15   22   26   28
```

Using the data of one file (e.g. file_04) as input, I would like to predict the likely progression of downloads based on the other files' downloads.

What is a suitable statistical approach to do this?

++ EDIT/NOTE ++
The word "file" refers to the observed entity, not the way of storing the data. There is just one data set, each row containing the cumulative download numbers over time.

Comment: Are you assuming that the time series in each of the files behave identically, but that   it just happens that the data is stored in different files, or is there some categorical distinction between the time series in each file?

Comment: Sorry, the use of the word "file" is confusing in this context and could be replaced by "observation". There is just one data set, each row contains the cumulative total download numbers over time of a file/observation.